# How do I use a color from theme options?

Tags: theme-development, css, theme-options, wp-enqueue-style

I am building a theme, and in the options I have created a place for link color. I cant seem to get this into the theme in any reasonable way. The best I can do is to put it after `wp_head` ... but that doesn't seem right. The color will be a hex color so I cant just set up style sheets for a fixed number of colors and enqueue one of those conditionally. I suppose I could do this with jQuery but I really hope to not have to resort to that. I imagine all I am looking for is some way to enqueue an inline style, but does such a concept exist and if not what is the best way to go about it. I really thought link color options and the like would be commonplace and easy to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would simply call that option inside of a callback, and hook it into `wp_print_styles` or `wp_head` (either one is semantically correct in this case).

First, set up your callback, which will print an *inline style sheet*:

```
function wpse74013_print_custom_styles() {
    ?>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse74013_print_custom_styles' );
```

The next step is to access your Theme option:

```
$options = get_option( 'my_theme_options' );
```

Now you need to apply the link color, which I'll assume is `$options['link_color']`, to your CSS. Let's assume that your link color is defined in `style.css` like so:

```
a { color:#0000FF; }
```

Simply replace the HEX value as appropriate:

```
a { color:#<?php echo $options['link_color']; ?>; }
```

Putting it all together in your callback:

```
function wpse74013_print_custom_styles() {
// Get Theme options
$options = get_option( 'my_theme_options' );
    ?>
<style type="text/css">
a { color:#<?php echo $options['link_color']; ?>; }
</style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse74013_print_custom_styles' );
```

And that's it! You should see your inline stylesheet output in your document head, with the user's setting output for the link color HEX value.

Comment: Thanks Chip, that's a fine comprehensive answer which I guess will be of benefit to others in the future as well as me now ... a veritable  mini tutorial even !

Answer (score 1):

`wp_head` is typically how it is done, at least for small cosmetic changes. What you should check out is the [Theme Customization API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API), specifically the `WP_Customize_Color_Control` and the tuturials links at the bottom of that page. That way you can hook into a preview and change colors on the fly with a build in color wheel, then save which color you want.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about the customizer too but am I wrong in thinking that to use the customizer I would first have to have it working the traditional way via the theme options. I have a few customizer settings and that's how I've done them ( ie implement a regular theme option and then get it working in the customizer )

Comment: Sort of, it would be easier to implement the Theme API, then if you have another custom area that needs those values use `get_theme_mod` and/or `set_theme_mod`, or just forget the theme API and hook your settings into `wp_head`.